# Incorrect ARC dimensions showing up in ezdxf

Tags: python, cad, ezdxf

I am using ezdxf to read some .dxf files. The goal is to read the file using ezdxf and access each entity the the drawing's modelspace to find arc lengths.

```
import ezdxf

file_path = "IRREGULAR.dxf"
doc = ezdxf.readfile(file_path)

msp = doc.modelspace()
for entity in msp:
    print(entity.dxftype())
    
    # I have some more code for other line types

    if entity.dxftype() == 'ARC':
        center_point = entity.dxf.center
        radius = entity.dxf.radius
        start_angle = entity.dxf.start_angle
        end_angle = entity.dxf.end_angle
        print(arc_length(radius, start_angle, end_angle))
```

I have created a function called arc_length that calculates arc lengths based on each arc's dimensions.

This is the irregular shape I am currently working with.

[shape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KtOVh.png)

This shape is broken down into multiple arcs.

I am viewing the same drawing on a CAD software to see how the arc lengths between my code and the  CAD software compare. The challenge is that out of the 6 arcs in this drawing, I am getting 5 dimensions that are exactly matching in both places. However, the rightmost arc length is way too off in my code. I verified and there are no additional layes or blocks that are unseen, and that I am looking at the same drawing in both places.

If I can get any help on how to fix this, or leads on what the potential issue could be, it would be extremely helpful. Thanks!

Something I tried was getting all arc dimensions and then recreating a shape using those. Surpringly, the shape after this reverse engineering turned out to be the correct shape that I started with. This is strange because if the arc dimensions were wrong, then I would have ended up with a weird shape.